# Dividing H in the Hurst power law function to get the Hurst exponent?

Tags: time-series, programming, regression, hurst-exponent

For my own learning I have been following the guide [here](http://www.bearcave.com/misl/misl_tech/wavelets/hurst/). It is highly instructive.

Implementing this in R I was able to reproduce the authors results on the data sets provided within some acceptable amount of error. However I noticed something funny. The data seems adjust up by exactly 0.50.

For a GBM process I got a value of approximately 1. The author of the website linked encounters nearly the same thing evaluating the raw Alcoa price series. This is wrong, obviously, since a GBM should have a value near 0.5.

There also seems to be a similar bias in the other data sets, and I have found generating a mean reverting data set results in a value in the .7x range, again obviously biased up almost 0.5.

This confused me because my math is correct per the website. Digging around I've stumbled on [this example website implementing it](https://flare9xblog.com/tag/hurst-exponent/). In there the author clearly indicates H is found by dividing the slope of the regression results by 2. Magically, my H is corrected using the same technique.

So this leaves me quite confused.

1. Why does the author of the bearcave not divide their H by 2?
2. What is the purpose of this division? What is the justification for it magically fixing my math?

Thank you!